# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::save()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, undefined, one-to-one, multiple-tables

I want to insert data into multiple tables (one to one), but i get error and in my database the column "metode_id" is null. i want the "metode_id" is not null

this is class "Transaksi" :

```
class Transaksi extends Model
{
    protected $table = "transaksi";
    protected $primarykey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['stok_kedelai', 'stok_ragi', 'harga_kedelai', 'harga_ragi'];

    public function metode()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Metode');
    }
public function pengguna()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Pengguna');
    }
}
```

This is class "Metode" :

```
class Metode extends Model
{
    protected $table = "metode";
    protected $primarykey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['bni', 'bri', 'mandiri', 'bca', 'btpn', 'ovo', 'gopay', 'dana'];

    public function transaksi()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Transaksi', 'metode_id');
    }
}
```

This is database of "Transaksi" :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('transaksi', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('pengguna_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('stok_kedelai');
        $table->integer('stok_ragi');
        $table->integer('harga_kedelai');
        $table->integer('harga_ragi');
        $table->bigInteger('metode_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('transaksi', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreign('pengguna_id')->references('id')->on('pengguna')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });

    Schema::table('transaksi', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreign('metode_id')->references('id')->on('metode')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

This is database of "Metode" :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('metode', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('bni')->nullable();
        $table->integer('bri')->nullable();
        $table->integer('mandiri')->nullable();
        $table->integer('bca')->nullable();
        $table->integer('btpn')->nullable();
        $table->integer('ovo')->nullable();
        $table->integer('gopay')->nullable();
        $table->integer('dana')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

i want insert data into mutiple table that which depends on the "id" of pengguna table but i get error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::save()

```
public function data_penjualan(Request $request)
{
    $pengguna = Pengguna::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    $transaksi = new Transaksi();
    $transaksi->stok_kedelai    = $request->stok_kedelai;
    $transaksi->stok_ragi       = $request->stok_ragi;
    $transaksi->harga_kedelai   = $request->harga_kedelai;
    $transaksi->harga_ragi      = $request->harga_ragi;
    $pengguna->transaksi()->save($transaksi);

    $metode = new Metode();
    $metode->bni = $request->bni;

    $transaksi->metode()->save($metode);

    return view('transaksi.supplier', compact('transaksi'));
}
```

this is my database, the "metode_id" get null, how i want that "metode_id" is not null :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svhk4.png)

Comment: Is the error at `$pengguna->transaksi()->save($transaksi);` line?

Comment: No. the error is $transaksi->metode()->save($metode);

Comment: Are you sure `$pengguna->transaksi()->save($transaksi);` doesn't give any error and if you do a `dd($transaksi->fresh())` immediately after it you get a record?

Comment: yes sure. after doing dd($transaksi->fresh()) i get a record but "metode_id" is null

Comment: Does the $transaksi record actually get persisted in database? Can you see it in database

Comment: yes the $transaksi is record in database except "metode_id"

Comment: Okay then try `$transaksi->fresh()->metode()->save($metode);` because the value of $transaksi is set to a new unperisited instance. So you need to pull the fresh record from database and then use relations on it. Till you pull a fresh instance from database it does not have an id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to update a `belongsTo` relationship, you have to use the `associate` method instead of `save` method.

```
...
    $metode = new Metode();
    $metode->bni = $request->bni;
    $metode->save();

    $transaksi->metode()->associate($metode);
    $transaksi->save();
...
```

Comment: it doesn't give any error, but I got no a record from $metode

Comment: @MyAugust I think that `Metode` object should be saved in database using `$metode->save();`. I updated my post.

Comment: Can be written as `$transaksi->metode()->associate($metode)->save()`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to SaveMethod in the belongsTo relationship.

> Add Comment(controller file)

```
public function addComment($id)
{   
    $comment = new Comment(['comment' =>'Comment 1']);
    $user = User::find(1);
    $user->comment()->save($comment);
    return "Comment Submitted";
}
```

> Comment.php        (Model File)

```
class Comment extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
  protected $table ="comments";
  protected $fillable = ['comment'];

  public function User()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 } 
}
```

> web.php (Route File)

```
Route::get('comment/{id}',[UserController::class,'addComment']);
```